# error in stationary wavelet transform python code

Tags: python, wavelet

I want to perform the following operation in python to detect and remove shadows as given in attached document.
(i) Convert the video frame from RGB to HSV
(ii) Split the HSV into h,s,v
(iii) Find the difference in h,s,v value of the reference and current frame
(iv) Apply the stationary wavelet transform (SWT) to the difference s and v
(v)perform the skew analysis on the wavelet output
(vi)assign the value to the pixels based on skew and wavelet output
(vii)Do the threshold operation to remove the shadows
(viii)Apply inverse SWT to reconsrtuct the image 
[REFERENCE PAPER](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318736562_Moving_shadow_detection_based_on_stationary_wavelet_transform)
I wrote the python script and got the following error while running swt command.

```
File "F:/Shoba/shadow_spinger.py", line 37,
  in <module> swts=pywt.swt(diffs,'db1',level=None,start_level=None)
File "C:\Users\pc13\Anaconda3\envs\pythonopencv\lib\site-packages‌​\pywt_swt.py", line 74,
  in swt ret = _swt_axis(data, wavelet, level, start_level, axis) 
File "pywt/_extensions/_swt.pyx", line 101,
  in pywt._extensions._swt.swt_axis (pywt_extensions_swt.c:5788) TypeError: an integer is required
```

My code is given below:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pywt
from scipy.stats import skew
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('cam4v.mp4')

while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    hsvImg=cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    #cv2.imshow('hsvImg',hsvImg)
    h,s,v=cv2.split(hsvImg)
    diffh=cv2.absdiff(h[1],h[0]).astype(np.uint8)
    diffs=cv2.absdiff(s[1],s[0]).astype(np.uint8)
    diffv=cv2.absdiff(v[1],v[0]).astype(np.uint8)
    print("diffh: {0} ".format(diffh))
    print("diffs: {0} ".format(diffs))
    print("diffv: {0} ".format(diffv))

    swts=pywt.swt(diffs,'haar',level=None,start_level=None)
    swtv=pywt.swt(diffv,'haar',level=None,start_level=None)
    skews=skew(swts)
    skewv=skew(swtv)
    swtv[skewv>swtv] = 255
    swtv[skewv<swtv] = 0
    swts[(skewv>swtv) & (skews>swts)] = 255
    swts[(skewv<swtv) & (skews<swts)] = 0
    iswts=pywt.iswt(swts,'haar',level=None,start_level=None,axes=None)
    iswtv=pywt.iswt(swtv,'haar',level=None,start_level=None,axes=None)


    finalhsv=cv2.merge((h,iswts,iswtv))
    cv2.imshow('frame',finalhsv)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:                     # exit if Escape is hit
      break

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

If you feel the question is too basic, dont downgrade it since I am newbie to python world. Also, suggest me the ways to get rid of this error in order to perform shadow removal task.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the complete error stacktrace

Comment: The error:File "F:/Shoba/shadow_spinger.py", line 37, in <module>
    swts=pywt.swt(diffs,'db1',level=None,start_level=None)

  File "C:\Users\pc13\Anaconda3\envs\pythonopencv\lib\site-packages\pywt\_swt.py", line 74, in swt
    ret = _swt_axis(data, wavelet, level, start_level, axis)

  File "pywt/_extensions/_swt.pyx", line 101, in pywt._extensions._swt.swt_axis (pywt\_extensions\_swt.c:5788)

TypeError: an integer is required